# ExtJS 5 - Order Grid Columns irrelevant of it array positioning

Tags: extjs, extjs5

Can someone help me to figure out a way to arrange the columns irrelevant of it columns array positioning? For example, in below grid columns array i just want to display Phone as 1st column and Name as 2nd column. How can i achieve that programmatically?

**Columns Array:-**

```
  columns: [{
        text: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name'
    }, {
        text: 'Email',
        dataIndex: 'email'
    }, {
        text: 'Phone',
        dataIndex: 'phone'
    }]
```

While debugging the grid column config with Chrome developer tools, i figured out a parameter **"fullColumnIndex"** which value getting increased for every column. But specifying that explicitly doesn't make any difference :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using `reconfigure` method. Docs — http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.panel.Table-method-reconfigure

Here is the description of this method:

> **reconfigure( [store], [columns] )**
>
> Reconfigures the grid / tree with a new store/columns. Either the store or the > columns can be omitted if you don't wish to change them.
>
> The enableLocking config should be set to true before the reconfigure method is > executed if locked columns are intended to be used.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *store* : Ext.data.Store (optional)
> The new store. You can pass null if no new store.
>
> *columns* : Object[] (optional)
> An array of column configs